# Fibonacci Sequence Algorithm

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am attempting to find the first number in the Fibonacci sequence to contain N digits (N being somewhere in the range of 500 and 2000). I attempt to do this with the following code:

```
BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.ONE;
int record = 0;
BigInteger TEN = BigInteger.valueOf(10);

public BigInteger run()
{
    BigInteger temp = BigInteger.ZERO;
    while(num2.compareTo(TEN.pow(SomeN - 1)) < 0)
    {
        if(num2.compareTo(TEN.pow(record + 1)) >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(""+record);
            record++;
        }

        temp = num1.add(num2);
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;

        num = num.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    System.out.println(""+num);
    System.out.println(""+num2);
    return num2;
}
```

The problem is, when I test for 1500 digits, the answer I get is apparently wrong. I do not know what the answer is supposed to be, and I have even checked the answers immediately around it in case my algorithm is off by a power of 10 (i.e. I checked 1499 digits and 1501), but to no avail. Anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: are you working on a project euler problem by any chance?

Comment: What is record supposed to be? I get the condition in the while clause, but not the one in the if inside.

Comment: Yes, I am. I am not looking for an answer, I am just stumped at what is wrong here. My approach is valid, and when I put println()s in to check the sequence printed, I am getting a correct sequence (at least for the first 40 or so integers) for fibonacci...

Comment: the purpose of record was to test for whenever I gain a new digit (record is the number of digits for the last 'record'). This doesn't really do anything here, but I was using earlier to print the cases at 10^(N-2), 10^(N-1), and 10^(N).

Comment: it doesn't appear to be a homework. This is a strange issue with very big numbers.

Comment: @Jonathan, how do you confirm you are getting wrong values?

Comment: This is not necessarily homework, OP said it was a Euler problem.

Comment: Why exactly do you think anything is wrong with your code? What problem do you see?

Comment: This is not homework. This is a problem (problem 25) from projecteuler (projecteuler.net). I am not looking for the solution, but for what is wrong here. I tested my answer by putting it in as a result for the problem. I think it would be highly unlikely that projecteuler as an incorrect result here, especially considering some number of people have answered correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the homework thing. I can't tell what's wrong with this code, but I can give a working solution using a different approach

Comment: @Paco: Not a problem. I can understand your frustration with people trying to have others do the learning for them. =)

Comment: @Paco: +1 for the apology. Not enought of us are willing to admit when we're wrong, nonetheless apologize for it.

Comment: Shouldn't `num1` be initialized using BigInteger.ZERO?

Comment: @mhaller: Umm... Good point. I'd say it doesn't matter here because I am checking against the VALUE of the variable in the sequence, but I think I need to return the index, so I will change that. Thank you. =)

Comment: Offtopic, you can write `System.out.println(record)` without the cargo-cult quotes.

Comment: Some more programming style hints: num doesn't need to be a BigInteger, and you should choose a different name to avoid confusion with num1 and num2 (which probably should be called fib-something). temp is needed only inside the loop, so better declare it there. BigInteger.TEN exists, you can use import static to use it. You could use .toString().length() to get the number of digits, IMHO that would be clearer (it's somewhat less efficient, but that doesn't matter here).

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you... I don't know exactly what was up earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(deleted way off base hint)

**EDIT: EP web site is back up, and the answer I get when using your code matches what the web site accepted as correct for me, way back when.**

Comment: it seems to work fine till at least the 500th number in the sequence :)

Comment: I double checked (again), and I do get 13 for input N=2, and 144 for N=3.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no reason to use a biginteger form here at all. log10 will suffice in one line of code. binet there, done that...